# using telegram tdlib in android projects

Tags: android, telegram

I want to use [tdlib](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib)  in my android project. Unfortunately I could not find any good tutorial about using this library.

I want that if user was registerd in telegram before and it is the first time that he want to use my app, the activation code is sent to him by sms not by telegram app as a message.

what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a such problem.
Now I'm trying to use this project:
https://github.com/kmormysh/Telegram
It has problems with old version libs and interfaces

Comment: Have you succeeded? I am trying to build a Telegram client for smartwatches